# c#. iText7. find tables in pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I have autocad drawing exported in PDF. Now I need edit main table in this pdf.[image]

I'm talking about the right bottom table. I need modify it with adding some text (red text on the picture). So the first problem is to find this table. I didn't find in iText examples/tutorials and API documentation how to find all the tables inside a pdf.
Could u please share some links or code example about how to list all the tables from pdf?
[Link to pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SKk40hHWz7pHxwPT-rJ-qMgq6RotSO9e/view?usp=sharing)
Thanks.

Comment: *"Could u please share some links or code example about how to list all the tables from pdf?"* - unless a pdf is tagged accordingly, there is no information about tables in it. Most likely your *right bottom table* merely corresponds to some scattered lines and pieces of text, each positioned somewhere in the lower right of the page.

Comment: Could you please share an example pdf so it can be checked if it is tagged?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse added link to initial post

Comment: The PDF does not contain structure information. Thus, don't count on a PDF library being able to automatically find the place where you want to add text. What you can do, though, is determine the position by measuring and drawing the additional text at the given coordinates.